# Can we control the [Setup] method execution before [Test] Method Execution in Selenium N unit

Tags: c#, selenium, frameworks, nunit, hybrid

Am just wondering how to solve this. I need to automate my company website. There I need to navigate more than one url for a multiple web pages. I have designed Hybrid framework along with Page object Model Design.

My Requirement is, 
say I have 3 url's :

www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
Facebook

All the above url and its test data I will keep in an Excel sheet. I have created three different pages and three different test classes. 
So my list of questions are:

1. How to pass url's one by one to [setup] method
2. how to call the test method deepening upon the url type

Execution Flow need to implement of Application:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Storing URL in excel is not good idea,

- You may store URL in app.config file and by using ConfigManager utility you may retrieve those URL from app.config file
- As according to your test cases you can use URL where its needed and required

Answer (score 1):

You need to parametrize your test with TestCase attribute.

```
[TestCase("www.google.com")]
[TestCase("www.yahoo.com")]
[TestCase("www.facebook.com")]
public void WebPageTest(string site)
{
  driver.Url(site);
  //continue with the test.
}
```

See this article to learn more: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCase-Attribute

Comment: Hi , Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs , still i have something in my mind . For an example if i have more than 1K urls need to tested , how do i proceed ?? Like if i store all 1K url's in the app.config ,how can i loop through each of that one in [Setup]

Comment: Hi i have more than 1k urls in my websites to automate which leads different page to be submitted   , how to proceed with them ? How to loop each url in the exact flow like this [SetUp]->[URL1 Test]->[Tear Down]->[Setup]->[URL2 Test]->[Tear Down]...continues like this . ??

Comment: @pradeep.k.sdeepu 1k URLs is very different than 3 as you put in your question. You should edit and update the info in your question to be more clear and more on the scale of the actual problem.

Comment: You can use [TestCaseData](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData) and read your 1k URLs from Excel or a db or a flatfile, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use [category] attribute to categorise your test cases. For example

```
[Test]
[Category("GoogleTest")]
public void googletest1()
{
}

[Test]
[Category("FBTest")]
public void fbtest1()
{
}
```

Now in the [SetUp] method you can load url based on the category, something like

```
[SetUp]
public void testsetup()
{
   #initialise driver 
   var category = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Keys;
            if(category.Contains("GoogleTest"))
            {
                   //category1 setup
            }
            else if(category.Contains("FBTest"))
            {
                //category2 setup
            }
}
```

So using this method you can solve query # 2, i.e the url related to the test is already loaded for you, so you can continue with your tests after setup

Comment: Hi , I have attached sample of test data on which am working . the number of urls will be more than 200 or 300 for my company website , so depending upon the test data , how can i design my framework using N unit and Page Object model ?